# ¿Por qué la descripción de web en Google no se actualiza?

Tags: google-search

Ya actualicé la descripción de una web hace más de una semana pero sigue saliendo la anterior que contiene errores, ¿cómo lo soluciono? ¿Cómo puedo hacer que Google actualice las descripciones de mi sitio web?

Comment: Básicamente Google la actualiza "cuando quiera".

Comment: :( gracias seguire esperando...

Comment: Puedes entrar en la consola de desarrollador web y pedir que reindexen tu sitio. mira los detalles en esta pregunta https://stackoverflow.com/a/15278642/6658955 Aunque sería bueno que alguien escribiera una respuesta en español :P

Comment: Sólo tienes que pedir a google que reindexe tu página principal, a través de Google Webmasters Tools. En cuestión de horas aparecerán los datos correctos. De paso, verifica en Google Webmasters Tools que todo está bien, y que tu sitio esté verificado por alguno de los métodos allí propuestos. Considero innecesario pasar por soluciones de terceros, cuando Google tiene una poderosa herramienta para hacerlo, y suele funcionar muy bien. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

> Respuesta traducida y adaptada de la [publicación de kevinmicke en Stack Overflow en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15278642/3695983).

Hay dos opciones. La primera (y mejor) es usando la opción Fetch en las Herramientas de Webmaster de Google, como comenta [Mike Flynn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/482591/mike-flynn) en el sitio en inglés. Aquí están las instrucciones detalladas sobre cómo hacerlo:

1. Navega a: https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/ y entra con tu usuario y contraseña
2. Si no lo has hecho aún, añade y verifica tu sitio con el botón "Añade un sitio" ("*Add a Site*").
3. Pulsa en el nombre del sitio que quieres gestionar
4. Pulsa en *Crawl -> Fetch as Google*
5. Opcional: si quieres hacer una página en particular, escribe la URL
6. Pulsa en *Fetch*
7. Pulsa en *Submit to Index* (Enviar al índice)
8. Selecciona "URL" o "URL y sus enlaces directos" ("*URL and its direct links*")
9. Pulsa en OK y ya está.

Con la opción de arriba, mientras que todas las páginas puedan accederse desde algún enlace de la página principal o una página enlazada desde la página principal, Google debería rastrear e indexar todo el sitio. Si quieres especificar una lista de las páginas que debe indexar en el dominio, puedes seguir las instrucciones para [mandar un sitemap](https://support.google.com/sites/answer/100283?hl=en).

Una segunda opción (y generalmente más lenta) sería, como [seanbreeden](https://stackoverflow.com/users/349260/seanbreeden) apunta en el sitio en inglés, enviar tus páginas a través del formulario en: http://www.google.com/addurl/

Comment: Echo a esperar...

Comment: Se soluciono con este consejo, ahora aparecen la descripción vieja y la nueva, supongo que cuando actualize el cache se solucionara. GRACIAS